# Apple Feedback Service returns device token in uppercase?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

Should we convert the device token returned by Apple to uppercase, Because feedback service always returns the device token in uppercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used equalsignorecase comparison, since we have unique constraint on it.

Answer (score 0):

It should not matter. It seems as if mine works fine with no modifications

Answer (score 0):

Upper or lower, it's the same value because it's the same token. It's depending o what you do with tokens, if the case must be insensitive or not.